# SenchaTouch 2 Send values to WebService - BEGINNER

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am following a `senchaTouch` tutorial. I have a Web service called `HelloWorld.php`, located in the URL `http://mydomainTest.com/Proj/HelloWorld.php`. It takes 3 values, `name`, `email` and `description`.

The web service uses `POST` method.

My code is as follows; What i want to know is that i haven't specified the Values for Keys (`POST` value Keys) and how will the web service know, what to save for the Keys (`name,email, description`)

When creating `native iPhone apps`, i use to say `setPostValue: forKey:` (in `ASIHttpRequest`), what i need to know is how to set the Key for the value passed in `Sencha`. I have attached my code below, please take a look and help me out.

```
Ext.define('GS.view.Contacts', {
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel', 
    xtype:'contactform',

        config:{
            title:'Contact',
            iconCls:'user',
            url:'http://mydomainTest.com/Proj/HelloWorld.php',

            items:[
                {
                    xtype:'fieldset',
                    title: 'Contact Us',
                    instructions: '(email is not required)',

                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            name: 'name',
                            label:'Name'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'emailfield',
                            name:'email',
                            label:'Email'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'textareafield',
                            name:'message',
                            label:'Message'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                items:[
                    {
                        xtype:'button',
                        text: 'Submit',
                        ui:'confirm',
                        handler: function(){
                            this.up('contactform').submit();
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
            ]
        }





} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps :-

- Get all the form values using `var values = Ext.getCmp('contactForm').getValues()` where contactForm is an `id` of this formpanel.
- Make an `Ext.Ajax request` and pass the params property the value of `values`
- Use a success handler to verify the success of request. Print the response text in the console log

Try this

```
 Ext.define('GS.view.Contacts', {
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel', 
    xtype:'contactform',
    id:'contactForm',
    config:{
            title:'Contact',
            iconCls:'user',
            items:[
                {
                    xtype:'fieldset',
                    title: 'Contact Us',
                    instructions: '(email is not required)',

                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            name: 'name',
                            label:'Name'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'emailfield',
                            name:'email',
                            label:'Email'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'textareafield',
                            name:'message',
                            label:'Message'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                items:[
                    {
                        xtype:'button',
                        text: 'Submit',
                        ui:'confirm',
                        handler: function(){
                          var values = Ext.getCmp('contactForm').getValues();
                          // prints the values filled in the form 
                          // text fields of name, email and message.     
                          console.log(values.name+","+values.email+","+values.message);                          


                          Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url: 'http://mydomainTest.com/Proj/HelloWorld.php',
                            params : values,
                            success: function(response){
                                var text = response.responseText;
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', text); 
                            }
                           });
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
            ]
        }
  } );
```

Comment: So like in ASIHTTRequest don't we have to specify, key-value pairs in Sencha. I don't see the key set for a Particular value in your code. Is this how Sencha works ?

Comment: And Part 2 of my question, if the server replies "SUCCESS", how can i print it in the Sencha App ?

Comment: Sencha's posting to Ajax request is simple. Get the form values, provide that values to `params` property of `Ext.Ajax.request` and then simply access those values at the php side using the same name .. i.e `name`, `email` and `message`

Comment: For your 2nd question, You can show the `responseText` you will be echo'ing from php script on to an `Ext.Msg.alert()` window.

Comment: One more thing, default method of Ajax request here is POST (in case params property is set). So no need to mention it explicitly.

Comment: One last question :) What hapence if i end up with a 408 response (request timed out), how should i make changes to the code to notify the user ?